# Negative current on power supply

Tags: power-supply

I've heard of linear power supplies that accept negative currents on the output, but I haven't found any documentation on this. I'll try to explain myself. Normally a power supply supplies current but, if the powered circuit is capable of supplying current that would be absorbed by the power supply.
No immediate problem to be solved, just curiosity for now. The next step will be to learn some possible implementations.

Comment: Kepco is the only company I know of that produces such a thing (but there probably are others). They might also be sold as "electronic loads" rather than as power supplies.

Comment: That said, can you make it more explicit what question you are asking about these products?

Comment: Consider the same as common power supply with low side transistor added. Btw , if you want a fast output response even during suppling (not loading) you need a low side transistor aswell.

Answer (score 3):

These are called four-quadrant-power supplies or bipolar supply, because they can work in multiple power quadrants (positive and negative power)

They are typically used in Source Measurement Units (SMU).

[image]
(source: [keysight](https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/kkbopen/what-is-a-bipolar-four-quadrant-power-supply-583425137.html))

Comment: If the voltage only needs to be _Positive_, there are also devices which ``Operate in two-quadrant mode as power source and regenerative electronic load`` such as the Keysight [RP7932A Regenerative Power System, 80 V, ±125 A, 5 kW, 200/208 VAC](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/RP7932A/regenerative-power-system-80v-125a-5kw-200-208vac.html). From the question not sure if a four-quadrant power supply is needed, of if a two-quadrant supply would be sufficient.

Comment: @ChesterGillon you can also get GW-Instek power supplies that can put a channel in load mode. The difference is if switching quadrants while active is a requirement.